# Difference between "als ob" / "als wenn"?

Tags: word-choice, subjunctive, comparison

I understand that the forms "als ob..." and "als wenn..." are grammatically used in the same way. But are they completely interchangeable? What is their difference?

For example, are both of the following correct? Do they sound different?

> Er tut immer so, **als ob** er Chef wäre.

and

> Er tut immer so, **als wenn** er Chef wäre.

I am not sure that my "als wenn" example is correct.

Comment: The alternative whith "als wenn" is colloquial, and maybe not compretely correct. A correct alternative would be "Er tut immer so, als wäre er Chef"

Comment: I think it's like in English ("as if" vs "as though"). It's just a matter of prevalence. Both are correct, "als ob" is more common.

Comment: @Beta: I can't find much about "als wenn" online but my course book suggests that the verb goes to the end. I am not sure about the tense though.

Comment: @Em1: I mainly wonder because there is a difference between "ob" and "wenn" themselves, but they seem the same when combined with "als +".

Comment: "if" and "though" in English are also quite different. But with "as" combined, they've got a common meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both versions are (grammatically) correct according to the [Duden](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/nebensaetze-mit-als-ob-als-wenn-wie-wenn):

> In irrealen Vergleichssätzen mit *als ob*, *als wenn* und *wie wenn* wird sowohl der Konjunktiv I als auch der Konjunktiv II verwendet [...]

Both versions mean the same and can be used that way.

– Nonetheless, to me, as native speaker, the second sentence with *als wenn* sounds a little off and I would prefer the one with *als ob*, especially if the sentence is accompanied with an expression of disapproval.

Comment: Is maybe "als wenn" better e.g. in the context of a theater play and imperative, e.g. "Do as if you were in the war"?

Comment: No, in the case of "pretend","imitate", etc. there is the fixed expression "so tun, als ob". 
 – I would stick to "als ob"! ;)

Comment: @MakisH As I stated in a comment above, "als ob" is way more common. Just go with "als ob" all the time. Add "als wenn" to your passive vocabulary.

Comment: ...unless you're visiting the southern of Germany where the people like to be grammatically incorrect and the common form is "als wenn" ;-)

Comment: I am actually learning german in Munich and I use books from a publisher located here! :-D